# Trying to use Python's Scrapy package, but it keeps returning empty values where it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

So I'm trying to scrape some rental information off of Kijiji. My program keeps returning empty values, where it shouldn't, then it crashes. I made a simplified version of my program:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# General set up.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Packages.
import os
import scrapy 
import requests
import re
import time
from math import ceil

# Change directory.
os.chdir("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Python/Projects/Kijiji Rental Prices")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Predefined variables.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Areas in northern BC.
regions = ['cariboo-area']

# Kijiji Area codes in northern BC.
region_codes = ['c37l1700296']

# Index set to one.
i = 0

# General posting variables.
url = []

# Empty lists for individual post scraping.
rental_type = []

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Scraping general posting data.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Loop to scrape general posting data.
while i < len(regions):

  # Set current page number to one.
  current_pg_num = 1

  # Web address.
  kijiji_page = "".join(["https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/", regions[i],
                "/page-", str(current_pg_num), "/", region_codes[i],
                 "?ad=offering"])

  # Download HTML page.
  html = requests.get(kijiji_page).content

  # Create selector to determine number of results.
  pg_num = scrapy.Selector(text = html)
  pg_num = pg_num.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='showing'])")
  pg_num = pg_num.extract()[0]

  # Create page count number.
  pg_num_reg = re.compile(r"\d+")
  pg_num = pg_num_reg.findall(pg_num)
  pg_num = ceil(float(pg_num[2]) / float(pg_num[1]))

  # Loop that iterates through page numbers.
  while current_pg_num < pg_num + 1:

    # Download HTML page.
    html = requests.get(kijiji_page).content

    # Create selector object for organic rent ads.
    pg = scrapy.Selector(text = html)
    pg = pg.xpath("//div[@class='info-container']")

    # Select advertisement URL.
    xpath_temp = "normalize-space(.//a/@href)"
    posting_url = pg.xpath(xpath_temp).extract()

    # Create full URLs.
    for index, link in enumerate(posting_url):
      posting_url[index] = "https://www.kijiji.ca" + link
    url = url + posting_url

    # Add page number index by one.
    current_pg_num += 1

    # Sleep for three seconds.
    time.sleep(3)

  # Add to regions index by one. 
  i += 1

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Individual posting scraping 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Loop to scrape individual postings.
  for index, link in enumerate(url):
    posting_html = requests.get(url[index]).content

    # Selector for posting.
    posting_sel = scrapy.Selector(text = posting_html)

    # Select rental type from posting.
    xpath_temp = "(//div[@class='unitRow-1281171205']//span/text())[1]"
    posting_rental_type = posting_sel.xpath(xpath_temp).extract()
    rental_type.append(posting_rental_type[0])

    # Sleep for three seconds.
    time.sleep(3)

  # Add page number index by one.
  current_pg_num += 1
```

I think it might have something to do with the actual requests to the server, but I'm unsure. Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You are trying to jump deeper into the tree of nodes but haven't checked for any undefined/null. For example, //div[@class='info-container'] might not be found just by looking into the output you showed.

Comment: "(//div[@class='unitRow-1281171205']//span/text())[1]" is what I'm using to get the rental type. It should be defined each time. Sometimes it returns a value, but sometimes it doesn't. The page is formatted the same each time.

Comment: Here is an example of an individual page result:
https://www.kijiji.ca/v-apartments-condos/williams-lake/1-bdrm-suite-in-williams-lake/1493849250

Comment: I tried scraping only every 30 seconds and it still breaks.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the web page downloaded in Chrome is different than the one downloaded by scrapy. I think I will have to figure out how to download a javascript page in python, then scrape that page.